# How to apply horizontal filter to my data?

Tags: python, filter, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing

I am generating the synthetic data to work with heatmaps.

[Example of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geGzC.png)

I was wondering if is there a way to "extend" data horizontally or apply a filter horizontally to make it seem that the values are related to time.

Any idea on how can I do that?

Here is the code and data I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data9.csv')

cl = sns.heatmap(data, cmap= 'viridis') 
plt.show()
```

You can download the CSV file from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTKpLZ_k8qzpdgQou-9kWB1d_02vFNYw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, you can use some sort of average filter for each station. If you can provide the matrix/array/data used for plotting that image so we can help.

Comment: Sorryy! First time using Stackoverflow I already put all the info. Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was to use a average-like filter in the horizontal axis. You must test other filters/kernels and if needed pad your input to avoid that vertical fading lines near the boundaries of the data. Also, if you want to blur only that circles you must find a Region Of Interest (ROI) around that area and then blur it.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("data9.csv").to_numpy()

plt.subplot(2, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(data, cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=40)
plt.title("Original")

# Average 3 elements
filter = np.ones(3)
for line in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[line] = np.convolve(data[line], filter, mode="same")/np.sum(filter)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(data, cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=40)
plt.title("Avg3")


# Average 5 elements
filter = np.ones(5)
for line in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[line] = np.convolve(data[line], filter, mode="same")/np.sum(filter)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(data, cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=40)
plt.title("Avg5")


# Average 7 elements
filter = np.ones(7)
for line in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[line] = np.convolve(data[line], filter, mode="same")/np.sum(filter)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 4)
plt.imshow(data, cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=40)
plt.title("Avg7")

# Average 3 elements with emphasis on central element
filter = np.array([1, 2, 1])
for line in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[line] = np.convolve(data[line], filter, mode="same")/np.sum(filter)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 5)
plt.imshow(data, cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=40)
plt.title("Avg3 Emphasis")

# Average 5 elements with emphasis on central element
filter = np.array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1])
for line in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[line] = np.convolve(data[line], filter, mode="same")/np.sum(filter)

plt.subplot(2, 3, 6)
plt.imshow(data, cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=40)
plt.title("Avg5 Emphasis")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Blurred data along the horizontal axis:
[image]